# Leetcode Question 586.Customer Placing the Largest Number of Orders Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to do a **Leetcode Question** (586.Customer Placing the Largest Number of Orders)
I have got an error (`Invalid use of group function`) How can I fix it?

````
SELECT o.customer_number
FROM Orders o
GROUP BY o.customer_number
HAVING COUNT(o.customer_number) = MAX(COUNT(o.customer_number));```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](//stackoverflow.com/q/1313120/90527)", "[return rows for values with MAX COUNT](//stackoverflow.com/q/26053732/90527)"

Answer (score 0):

First make a subquery to get the count(order_number) for each customer,then use MAX function to determine the highest from the subquery's result set. Finally the main query will choose the customer with the most count(order_number) :

```
select customer_number from orders 
    group by customer_number 
    having count(order_number) =
        (select max(c) from 
            (select count(order_number) c
            from orders 
            group by customer_number) t
        )
;
```